# Content search web part required for Crawl

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, content-search-web-part, crawl

I have created the Content search image slider web part in SharePoint 2013.I have added the images . but the images are not showing in Image Slider.It's showing only After completing the "crawl".Start crawl Is the only way to show the images ?
Because for every new image requires for crawl completion. Is there any other way to show image except start the crawl method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not only case with images, any content you add to sites will be available in search result only after new content is crawled, though you don't need to run it manually every time. it will automatically ran every 15 minutes with incremental crawl timer job.... you might also want to enable continuous crawl for freshness of data... below is some details about crawls...

Incremental Crawls are search crawlers that gather the changes made since the last crawl. Incremental Crawls and Full Crawls cannot be run in parallel. They take charge and hog the whole crawler resource. This also makes it possible to have very outdated search results. An incremental crawl may not pick up changes that happen while the incremental crawl is running. Continuous Crawl fixes this problem. It may spawn several sessions in 15 minute intervals, that will pick up the changes as well as the changes made during the Continuous Crawl. It will maximize the freshness of your search content.

There is an excellent write up that explains the what's how's and why's of Continuous Crawl. http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2012/09/14/how-can-i-achieve-the-best-freshness-of-search-results-introducing-continuous-crawls-for-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: So, the Content search web part always depends on crawl ?

Comment: yes... better to use image library and create custom slider....

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior, If you add something into your site( images, pages, content etc) that stuff will not be available for search immediately. In order to get the results you have to wait for one of the configured options

- Continuous Crawl
- Incremental Crawl
- Full crawl.

Once any of the above crawl complete then you will see the result in search.

Content Search Web Part is just an interface infront of Search Service, it will get the same result as user get in the search center.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15571.sharepoint-2013-continuous-crawl-and-the-difference-between-incremental-and-continuous-crawl.aspx